# XSL conditions: how to choose a value from list only when the condition is met?

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement a logic which would do choosing a value if it matches the condition. The problem is, if my list contains more elements than one, it wouldn't display the value which matches the condition, but only the first one. Could you provide some advice? thanks. I need this to implement multiple filtering by conditions. Meaning that in this for-each I would display only books with year 2008, but in another table I could also use 2010 from the list of years. The below example is a part of the template for one table which uses 2008, but I will have multiple tables where I would filter books by 2010 as well.

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="years">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="year=2008">
            <td class="year"><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

XML:

```
    <book>
        <title>Professional ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB</title>
        <author>Bill Evjen, Scott Hanselman, Devin Rader</author>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>580</price>
        <years>
            <year>2010</year>
            <year>2008</year>
        </years>
        </book>
```

This one would populate **2010** into my HTML, not **2008** as I would expect. Is this doable at all?

Update:

I've tried this approach for example to filter against multiple conditions separately:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="library/book">
            <tr>
              <td class="filterTd title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
              <td class="filterTd author"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
              <td class="filterTd price"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
              <xsl:for-each select="years/year[.2008]">
              <td class="year">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="years/year[.2010]">
              <td class="year">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
```

This would not populate any td at all in my case..

Comment: Assuming you are in the context of `book`, try `<xsl:for-each select="years/year[.=2008]">`. Then you won't need the `xsl:if`.

Comment: Of course, if there can be only one `<year>2008</year>` you could get rid of the `xsl:for-each` and do simply: `<xsl:if test="years/year=2008"><td class="year">2008</td></xsl:if>`.

Comment: doesn't work for me, generated td cell is empty then. Maybe there is still a way to do it with if/when?

Comment: the last approach doesn't work for me, I would need to go through the list of years a filter by a specific one. later this would be done in multiple places for filtering.

Comment: See #1 working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKR. #2 can work with a variable.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. Could we somehow do comparison against several conditions, not only one? For example, one condition would output if the year is 2008, another when 2010. Because in my own app I will use it for filtering against multiple conditions. I would have a book with a list of years and in my template I would need to pick books to a list of 2008, to a list of 2010, etc.

Comment: I am not sure I follow this. I suggest you expand your question - see: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for a remark, I've added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display books for a specific year, you would put a condition in the `xsl:for-each` that selects the book

```
<xsl:for-each select="library/book[years/year=$year]">
```

Where $year is a variable (or parameter) containing the year you want

Do note, if you know you are dealing with a specific year, then you don't actually need to do `<xsl:value-of select="year" />`, you can just output the year value you are working with.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="table">
      <xsl:with-param name="year" select="2008" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="table">
    <xsl:param name="year" />
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="library/book[years/year=$year]">
        <tr>
          <td class="filterTd title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td class="filterTd author"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
          <td class="filterTd price"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
          <td class="year">
            <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you could also use a key here to look up  books by year

```
<xsl:key name="booksByYear" match="book" use="years/year" />
```

Then, the `xsl:for-each` to select books, looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('booksByYear', $year)">
```